# Setting up a NSDictonary with NSSet objects

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsset

Is there a way to setup a NSSDictionary with NSSet objects in one command?  Or, do objects need to be created for all of the sets first?

For example, is something like this possible?

```
NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:{@"orange",@"lemon"},@"citrus",{@"horse",@"moose",@"goose"},@"animals",nil];
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Not sure if that general scheme is legal or not, but if so it's backwards -- objects first, keys second, in the ObjectsAndKeys list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no NSSet literal, no.  But you can use an NSArray literal to initialise an NSSet… it's about the shortest you can get:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
    @"citrus":  [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"orange", @"lemon"]],
    @"animals": [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"horse", @"moose", @"goose"]]};
```

Comment: Probably better than this is just using `[NSSet setWithObjects:@"orange", @"lemon", nil]`. That way you aren't creating and destroying an array for nothing.

Comment: There are trade-offs, though, like having to worry about correct nil termination.  Unless performance is an issue, I'd err on the side of the harder-to-screw-up approach.

Comment: The compiler will immediately inform you if you did not correctly nil terminate the list of arguments. Using +[NSSet setWithArray:] has a runtime impact every single time the program is run.

+[NSSet setWithObjects:] is a lot more common of a pattern.

Comment: The compiler can't warn you if one of your parameters is accidentally nil, such as if it's the result of a method or function call, and thus terminates your list prematurely.  It's a very insidious bug to be afflicted by, though luckily fairly rare.

Comment: Ah, I see, that is true. In this case, though, since all the elements are literals I think it's safe to use setWithObjects.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `NSSet` literal in Objective-C only `NSArray` literals.

`NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"citrus" : @[ @"orange", @"lemon" ], @"animals" : @[ @"horse", @"moose" ,@"goose" ] };`

So the above will give you a `NSDictionary` with an `NSArray` containing `orange` and `lemon` for the key `citrus` and an `NSArray` containing `horse`, `moose`, and `goose` for the key `animals`.

You could access those `NSArrays` like so
`dictionary[@"animals"] and dictionary[@"citrus"]`

You can nest those literal accessors as well so
`dictionary[@"animals"][0]` would give you `horse`.

or even use array methods

`[dictionary[@"citrus"] count]` would give you `2`

Comment: Thanks for explaining all those shortcuts, much appreciated!